# MySQL concatenate a string to a column

Tags: mysql

What I'm trying to do its edit the information from a row adding more data, for example:

```
select name, obs from users where area='it'
```

It gives me:

```
name       obs
charles    vegetarian
xena       otaku
```

and I want to add to the their obs 'friendly hard worker'

I have tried:

```
update users set obs=obs+' frienly hard worker' where area='it'
```

but it didn't work, the result that I want is:

```
name       obs
charles    vegetarian frienly hard worker
xena       otaku frienly hard worker
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

In MySQL, the plus sign `+` is an operand for performing arithmetic operations.

You need to use the `CONCAT()` function to concatenate strings together.

```
UPDATE users 
SET obs = CONCAT(obs,' frienly hard worker') 
WHERE area='it';
```

Answer (score 3):

```
update users set obs= CONCAT('string1', column1 , 'string2', column1 , 'string3' ) where area='it'
```