# How can I merge rows from two joined tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

There are two tables, which can be joined, and the relationship is `1 to many`. I wish the rows of results to be merged.

For example:

Table 1: contacts

```
.------------.----------.
| contact_id | username |
:------------+----------:
|          1 | user1    |
:------------+----------:
|          2 | user2    |
:------------+----------:
|          3 | user3    |
'------------'----------'
```

Table 2: documents

```
.-------------.------------.----------.
| document_id | contact_id | filename |
:-------------+------------+----------:
|           1 |          1 | abc.txt  |
:-------------+------------+----------:
|           2 |          1 | bcd.txt  |
:-------------+------------+----------:
|           3 |          1 | cde.txt  |
:-------------+------------+----------:
|           4 |          2 | 123,txt  |
:-------------+------------+----------:
|           5 |          2 | 234.txt  |
:-------------+------------+----------:
|           6 |          3 | xyz.txt  |
'-------------'------------'----------'
```

The result I wish I can get:

```
.------------.----------.---------------------------.
| contact_id | username |         filenames         |
:------------+----------+---------------------------:
|          1 | user1    | abc.txt, bcd.txt, cde.txt |
:------------+----------+---------------------------:
|          2 | user2    | 123.txt, 234.txt          |
:------------+----------+---------------------------:
|          3 | user3    | xyz.txt                   |
'------------'----------'---------------------------'
```

Updated:

```
SELECT c.contact_id, c.username, GROUP_CONCAT(d.filename) as filenames 
FROM contacts c 
LEFT JOIN documents d 
ON c.contact_id = d.contact_id 
GROUP BY c.contact_id
```

Comment: use group_concat
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: @jungle . . . What have you tried?  This is pretty simple application of `JOIN`, GROUP BY` and `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

Comment: Hi, @HariramanRadhakrishnan, could you kindly show me the code? Sorry, I am not familiar with group_concat, I found it before, but I did not know how to use it to archive the above. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff, sorry I have tried. Due to lack of SQL knowledge, I did not succeed.

Comment: Let me try again @HariramanRadhakrishnan, Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL concatenate a string to a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14282369/mysql-concatenate-a-string-to-a-column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really post your attempts with your question, so that we can see what you have tried. In that way, it will be easy to push you in the right direction, as well as give the rest of us the impression that you have put some effort into the matter before asking the question. Stackoverflow is not a coding service.

To answer your question,

What you would like to do in this case, is to perform an `INNER JOIN` on your two tables, and have the MYSQL function, `GROUP_CONCAT();`, in your `SELECT` statement.

When you look at your two tables, you have a coherent id (contact_id) that you should use in your `INNER JOIN` to link your two tables together.

You then, at the end, need to perform a `GROUP BY` to *group* your results accordingly, i.e. to *group* the results by *contact_id*.

Your SQL would look something like this:

```
SELECT
  tbl_contacts.contact_id,
  tbl_contacts.username,
  GROUP_CONCAT(tbl_documents.filename) as file_name
FROM
  tbl_contacts
INNER JOIN
  tbl_documents ON tbl_contacts.contact_id = tbl_documents.contact_id
GROUP BY
  tbl_contacts.contact_id
```

[Working SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4feb/10)

Comment: Hi, @Martin, Thanks for your comments. Yes, you are right. Next time, when I ask a question here, I will mind my manners. According to your answer, I updated mine.

Comment: Does that mean that the question has been disclosed, or? Consider accepting an answer that you found useful to disclose Your question.